# How to access to actual Component when using ref and having ProxyComponent

Tags: reactjs, ref, refs

We have a ref to a react component and want to call a method of this component.
When using the ref it is a "ProxyComponent" object.
How can I use it as my actual component or what to do to be able to do this.
I saw, that there is the attribute "renderedElement" and inside the attribute "type" which is the correct type of my actual component. But I didnt find a way to use it like this/to call my components methods.

Comment: Sorry, I delete my answers for folks that don't mark questions as answered.

Comment: Sorry, I am not very experienced with stackoverflow yet. I have just marked the one of my 3 questions which is already finished as complete/answered. Thank you for the hint.