# How do I get the wrapped component from ProxyComponent?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When using material-ui(**^1.0.0-beta.24**) and adding JSS Styles to my component as such:

```
class Counter extends Component{ 
  getCount= () => {
   return this.state.count;
  }
}

export default withStyles(stylesJss)(Counter);
```

Accessing the counter component via the "ref" prop in the parent component like:

```
 <Counter ref={(ref) => this.counter = ref} />
```

`this.counter` results in a `ProxyComponent` object instead of the underlying Counter class due to the `withStyles` wrapper. I would like to access the Counter class and it's method(s) like such: `this.counter.getCount()` from the parent and use it as a standard React uncontrolled component. How can this be obtained?

Comment: Do you really need the `ref`? In most cases it's not needed, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to get a value from the Counter component in an "uncontrolled" fashion. In the parent I`d like to do something like this: let count = this.counter.getSomeValue();

Comment: Seems similar to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38077572/how-to-access-to-actual-component-when-using-ref-and-having-proxycomponent

Answer (score 0):

You can access the wrapped components ref via the innerRef property

```
<Counter innerRef={(ref) => this.counter = ref} />
```